# How to get chunks of data from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a callback to load more data on scroll but I can't figure out how to increase the number for this each time. I'd like to replicate this functionality except increase by +20 each time.

```js
const [sequential, setSequential] = useState(withImages.slice(0, 20));
const fetchMoreData = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setSequential(withImages.slice(0, 40))
    }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable that stores size and increase it when `setSequential` is invoked.

```js
let i = 20;

const [sequential, setSequential] = useState(withImages.slice(0, i));
const fetchMoreData = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setSequential(withImages.slice(0, (i += 20)))
    }, 100);
};
```